# Does a ModelInstance in a MultibodyPlan have a unique source_id for determining if a geometry_id belongs to it?

Tags: drake

I have a `MultibodyPlant` which has several robots in it, each of which is a `ModelInstance` and they are added to the plant using `AddModelInstance`. During collision, I would like to determine which of these model instances a colliding object (tagged by a geometry_id) belongs to.

I was trying something like

```cpp
// register the model instance
const auto robot_model_index {
          Parser(robots_plant_, scene_graph_)
              .AddModelFromFile(entity->urdf, entity->name)};
/*
lots of code
*/
const auto& query_object {
      query_port.Eval<QueryObject<double>>(*plant_context_)};
const auto& inspector {query_object.inspector()};
// determine the source_id of a given model_instance
// does not work
const auto& my_robot_id {robot_model_index.get_source_id().value()};

// query ownership
bool belongs_to_my_robot {inspector.BelongsToSource(signed_distance_pair.id_A, robot_id)};
```

How can I query ownership of a given `geometry_id` to a `ModelInstance` within a multibody plant? Am I missing some easy helper function which gives a `source_id` for a `ModelInstance`? Or another way to query ownership rather than `BelongsToSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `MultibodyPlant` has a unique `SourceId`. So, all geometries registered through the `MBP` (e.g., via parsing), will be associated with the *plant*'s `SourceId`. But there's good news. When `MultibodyPlant` registers frames and geometries with `SceneGraph`, it *stores* the model instance index with the frame. `SceneGraph` calls it the "frame group".

So, if your goal is to map `GeometryId` to `ModelInstanceIndex`, you'd have to do the following:

```cpp
const ModelInstanceIndex robot_model_index =
    Parser(robots_plant_, scene_graph_)
        .AddModelFromFile(entity->urdf, entity->name);

// Lots of code.
const auto& query_object {
      query_port.Eval<QueryObject<double>>(*plant_context_)};
const auto& inspector {query_object.inspector()};
const SignedDistancePair<double>& signed_distance_pair = ...;

const FrameId frame_id =
    inspector.GetFrameId(signed_distance_pair .id_A);
// The frame group of a frame registered by MBP *is* its
// model instance index.
const ModelInstanceIndex geo_model_instance_index =
    inspector.GetFrameGroup(frame_id);
bool belongs_to_my_robot = geo_model_instance_index == robot_id;
```